# Increase a counter when a command is called

Tags: macros, counters

I would like to increase a counter whenever the command `\item` is called.

Of course, the following code

```
\renewcommand{\item}{\item\stepcounter{counterNbQuestions}}
```

will not work.

How can I do?

---

### Edit

The following code does work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{totcount}

\newtotcounter{mycounter}
\preto\item{\refstepcounter{mycounter}}

\begin{document}

Total : \total{mycounter} items

\begin{enumerate}
\item Test
\item Test
\item \begin{enumerate}
\item Test
\item Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: etoolbox `\prepto\item{\refstepcounter{...` (really you should put it before not after, as otherwise you break the optional argument `\item[zzz]` otherwise use `\appto`)

Comment: The above comment is the general case for _any_ command, but for `\item` it already is configured to increment a counter (so `enumerate` works) You have given no use case but probably you should just define a standard latex list using the `counterNbQuestions` counter, either directly or using the `enumitem` package.

Comment: Your solution seems not to work. I will create a MWE. I need to stick to `enumerate` environments and the `\item` command. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Question edited: I have added a MWE

Comment: you should of course do what I _mean_ not what I _type_ sorry try `\preto`  (no middle p)

Comment: Self-answers are perfectly admissible but you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code does work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{totcount}

\newtotcounter{mycounter}
\preto\item{\refstepcounter{mycounter}}

\begin{document}

Total : \total{mycounter} items

\begin{enumerate}
\item Test
\item Test
\item \begin{enumerate}
\item Test
\item Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```